# Get data value from .click by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This code will output the right class name but not the right data-validamount.
it will only output : undefined.

```
$(".prod_amount_add").click(function(){     
    var rowAmount = 0;
    var datavalid = $(this).attr('data-validamount');   
    console.log(datavalid);
    console.log($(this).attr('class'));
});

<div class="prod_amount_add">
    <img src="icons/add.png" width="16" height="16" 
         alt="Plus 1" data-validamount="1">   
</div>
```

Comment: the attribute is on your `img`, not your `.prod_amount_add` div

Comment: `this` in your context is the `div` wrapper, not `img`. If you want to get the img element, please use `$(this).children('img')`, it's better than `.find()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute is on your `img`, not your `.prod_amount_add` div, so you'd do `$(this).find('img').attr('data-validamount');`

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(this).find('img').data('validamount')`.

Comment: You should explain your answer in more detail. What does it do and why should it work?

Comment: I think that the answer speaks for itself and I often like the answers that are short and concise rather full of irrelevant text. But if you really really want some text: It finds the img tag and gets its data-validamount attribute using data() function. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

you need to find your img attr after click on div . as it is part of img not of div

```
$(".prod_amount_add").click(function(){

    var rowAmount = 0;  

    var datavalid = $(this).find('img').attr('data-validamount');   
    console.log(datavalid);
    console.log($(this).attr('class'));

    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/LdJJt/)